# different Paramters for one Job Agent

Tags: simulation, anylogic

[Simulation_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzko2.png)
[MyAgent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXr1Q.png)

i've built this model, now i want to use DB to get different processing times for each station. so if one of my "Jobs" (myAgent) goes trough a service station it will have different delay times at each station depend on my parameters. i've built the model an have 1 Agent that have the parameters (maschine1-maschine5) with different delay times. in each Service station i call the Delay Time by this (agent.maschine1). so it gets the delay Time from the parameter maschine1 from my Agent MyAgent.

How can i now use Database to get more Parameters and call for each "Job=MyAgent" the Delay Times from my Database.
[Database with delay times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRXO5.png)

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You actually ask *several* questions at once. Please split these into several, separate questions. For each, make them easily answerable and show you already put some work into the problem. This helps you and others in the future with similar issues. Some more tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create all your agents using the database,
This is explained in amazing detail here:

https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/agent-db.html

Now you will have agents with your 5 parameters, and you will need to make them enter the system... so instead of the source block, you will use an enter block, and on main startup (see the main properties) you will do

```
for(MyAgent a : myAgents){
    enter.take(a);
}
```

then in each machine you can use the delay as for example in the delay section of maschine1 you will write

```
agent.maschine1
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe, i have a further question. i tried to use a button with traceln(agent.maschine5) to get the Delay time to check if its use the right delay. but i get an error: agent cannot be resolved or is not a field. Can u maybe tell me how i can fix this ?   Best regards Mo

Comment: Please do (all) the step-by-step tutorials of AnyLogic first, you will learn so many basic concepts before diving deeper, such as understanding your problem here -> https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html . 100% worth your time :)

Comment: @Mo1409 anylogic cannot guess what agent is if you put it in a button... you really need to go through the basics... take our courses at noorjax.teachable.com

Comment: i already found a way to check the delay time by using statistics in the Service Block. I did some tutorials but somehow they don't really help if u got some special questions. Thank u very much Felipe for the help.